# Не могу установить curl в qt

Tags: c++, qt, curl

Хочу работать с библиотеками curl в программе QT Creator, но не могу нормально установить. Код написал самый простой:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main(void)
{
    CURL *pars;
    pars = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_cleanup(pars);
}
```

Ошибки получились такие -> [image: ошибки]

В .pro введено:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2021-01-28T12:30:33
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = new_p
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp
INCLUDEPATH += C:/OpenSSL-Win32/include
LIBS += -LC:/OpenSSL-Win32/
LIBS += -LC:/OpenSSL-Win32/lib -llibssl
LIBS += -LC:/OpenSSL-Win32/lib -llibcrypto

INCLUDEPATH += C:/Curl/include/curl
LIBS += -LC:/Curl/bin -llibcurl
```

Папка с curl находится на диске "C", поэтому в .pro путь указан верно.

Comment: два вопроса - какой компилятор и откуда либы

Comment: -llibcurl? А не -lcurl случаем?

Comment: "-llibcurl? А не -lcurl случаем?". Не знаю, брал с интернета, но если изменяю на "-lcurl", то все равно те же ошибки

Comment: `LIBS += -LC:/Curl/bin` в конце должно быть lib, а не bin.